# Embedding open graph video doesn't use video player

Tags: facebook, video, fbml, flowplayer, facebook-opengraph

I've been in, around, and through a good chunk of the internets looking for an answer to this:

I'm trying to embed a video in Facebook using the og:video tag, but despite the fact that the facebook linter keeps showing 'status: Video embedding on Facebook enabled', when it shows up in my feed, clicking on it always opens a new window instead of showing it in the video player.  It does show a little play icon, but it acts like a link rather than a video.

I've tried it with an swf url that works when i hit it, i've tried it with an mp4 video, I've tried https, http, etc.  My og tags are pretty much exactly like this example I see at http://ahrengot.com/playground/circular-scrubbing/ (theres a good tutorial at http://ahrengot.com/tutorials/custom-video-player-on-facebook/).

Do I need to associate it with an app (have tried that and just using my user id in fb:admins), and if so, what kind of settings do I need to set to make it show up in a video player?  Do I need to set up a canvas url?

I'm using flowplayer.

Thanks for any help.

Edit: it seemed to spontaneously start working after trying for 8 hrs.  Does facebook do some kind of testing/caching of the target before it allows the embed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, I'm not sure on how often..but to update facebook's cache of a specific URL, run it through the debugger (formerly URL linter) @ http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 0):

Might also be SSL related. If you have secure browsing enabled on FB it will launch your video in a new window. The link of the video you are embedding with og:video is using "http" and not "https".